Can I just turn off main water supply to house to change hot water stem in bath tub or do I have to drain water heater?
Can I just turn off main water supply line to house to replace a hot water valve to bath tub or do I have to drain hot water heater?

Is the heater gas or electric? If gas, turn the control to pilot or to vacation. If electric, turn off the power at the heater if there is a switch there or flip the breaker off.

You should have a water turnoff on your tank.

If you have a shut off at the cold inlet to the HW tank, you can shut off the water there. If not then you will need to shut off the main valve into the house.
Do you need to drain the tank?  It's hard to say. It depends on where the tank is and will siphoning occur.  In most cases it is a minor amount of water that will be dispelled.  What is important is you don't want the water level in the tank to go below the heating elements and have them burn out.  So be safe and turn the power to the tank off.

Is the heater gas or electric? If gas, turn the control to pilot or to vacation. If electric, turn off the power at the heater if there is a switch there or flip the breaker off.
Normally in old style two-handle installations neither the tub nor shower has cutoff valves as under the kitchen sink or a lavatory. If you turn off the cold supply to the water heater, this would be expected to stop the flow of hot water from the tub, but sometimes when the hot water pressure is reduced to zero one or more single lever faucets in the kitchen or in a bathroom will allow cold water to leak into the hot line and you could get dripping out the hot bathtub valve opening. If you get this, simply turn off the HOT supply cut-off valves to the single lever faucets under the sink or lavatory. This will prevent cold water flowing backwards into the hot water lines. If you are having to turn off all the water to the house, then this is not necessary.
